# Finding force from torque equation

Tags: forces, torque, magnetic-moment

I have read an article on electrostatics textbook that, 
$$\vec {F}= \nabla {\vec {\tau} }$$
Such as,the toraue equation on a magnetic dipole is $$ \vec\tau={\frac{{\mu}_0 m^2}{2\pi z^3} }\hat{z} $$
The the force on this dipole is   $$\vec{F}=-{\frac{{3\mu}_0 m^2}{2\pi z^4} } \hat {z}$$
Can anyone help me proving this?

Comment: Is that supposed to be the curl? Because the gradient of a vector is generally a dyad (a tensor) and divergence a scalar

Comment: Where did you read this, in particular?